# Nohup process not killed by kill command

Tags: c++, linux, nohup, ptrace

In my c++ code I handle signals and everything works fine. However, when I launched it by nohup in standard way, kill  not working, I have to kill it with -9. 
Launching /proc/PID/status before kill state is S (Sleeping), after kill I received:

```
State:  T (tracing stop)
3 Tgid:   21280
4 Pid:    21280
5 PPid:   1
6 TracerPid:  1
25 SigPnd: 0000000000000000
26 ShdPnd: 0000000000004000
27 SigBlk: 00007f06782a1000
28 SigIgn: 0000000000000001
29 SigCgt: 0000000180004006
```

It seems to me that the issue is in being traced by another process (state changed), because proper signals are enabled. It is traced by init. I don't know why, because other processes don't behave in such way, I mean: they aren't traced and are killed by kill command.

Thank You for any suggestions.

Comment: Ok, it turns out, that static library, written by one of my colleagues , which is linked in link time handle all signals ;].